# Changing Rowspan Not Working in Tkinter Grid

Tags: python, tkinter, tkintermapview

I am trying to create a UI with two different screens that the user can change between using a button at the top of the screen.

I have placed the button in row 0 and the frames for the other screens in row 1 however the button is appearing halfway down the screen within the frame that is supposed to be in row 1.

[The current UI (there should be more labels at the bottom on this screen but they have gone of the edge of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbbt9.png)

Code:

```py
class TaskInputFrame(GeneralFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.enter_task_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Enter Task", command=self.enter_task)

        self.turnpoint1_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Turpoint 1:"))
        self.turnpoint2_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Turpoint 2:"))
        self.turnpoint3_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Turpoint 3:"))
        self.turnpoint4_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Turpoint 4:"))
        self.turnpoint5_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Turpoint 5:"))
        self.pilot_mass_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Pilot Weight:"))
        self.desired_wing_loading_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Desired Wing Loading:"))

        self.turnpoint1_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.turnpoint2_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.turnpoint3_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.turnpoint4_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.turnpoint5_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.pilot_mass_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.desired_wing_loading_entry = ttk.Entry(self)

    def place_widgets(self):
        self.enter_task_button.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky = tk.W, pady=3)

        self.turnpoint1_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.turnpoint2_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.turnpoint3_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.turnpoint4_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.turnpoint5_entry.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.pilot_mass_entry.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.desired_wing_loading_entry.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)

        self.turnpoint1_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E, pady=3, padx=1)
        self.turnpoint2_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=3, padx=1)
        self.turnpoint3_label.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.E, pady=3, padx=1)
        self.turnpoint4_label.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.E, pady=3, padx=1)
        self.turnpoint5_label.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=tk.E, pady=3, padx=1)
        self.pilot_mass_label.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=tk.E, pady=3, padx=1)
        self.desired_wing_loading_label.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)

    def forget_widgets(self):
        self.enter_task_button.grid_forget()

        self.turnpoint1_entry.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint2_entry.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint3_entry.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint4_entry.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint5_entry.grid_forget()
        self.pilot_mass_entry.grid_forget()
        self.desired_wing_loading_entry.grid_forget()

        self.turnpoint1_label.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint2_label.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint3_label.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint4_label.grid_forget()
        self.turnpoint5_label.grid_forget()
        self.pilot_mass_label.grid_forget()
        self.desired_wing_loading_label.grid_forget()

    def enter_task(self):
        pass

class TaskOutputFrame(GeneralFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.task_duration_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Task Duration:"))
        self.optimal_launch_time_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Optimal Launch Time:"))
        self.finish_time_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Finish Time:"))
        self.optimal_wing_loading_label = ttk.Label(self, text=str("Optimal Wing Loading:"))
    
    def place_widgets(self):
        self.task_duration_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.optimal_launch_time_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.finish_time_label.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)
        self.optimal_wing_loading_label.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.E, pady=3)

    def forget_widgets(self):
        self.task_duration_label.grid_forget()
        self.optimal_launch_time_label.grid_forget()
        self.finish_time_label.grid_forget()
        self.optimal_wing_loading_label.grid_forget()

class MapFrame(GeneralFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.map = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(width=600, height=570, corner_radius=3)

        self.map.set_position(50.853060, -3.269220)

        self.turnpoint1 = self.map.set_marker(50.853060, -3.269220, text="NHL")
        self.turnpoint2 = self.map.set_marker(50.991271, -3.491076, text="BAM")
        self.turnpoint3 = self.map.set_marker(50.897219, -2.642515, text="YEO")
        self.turnpoint4 = self.map.set_marker(50.853060, -3.269220, text="NHL")

        self.task = self.map.set_path([self.turnpoint1.position, self.turnpoint2.position, self.turnpoint3.position, self.turnpoint4.position])

    def place_widgets(self):
        self.map.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=15, pady=15, sticky=tk.E)

    def forget_widgets(self):
        self.map.grid_forget()
    
class TaskFrame(GeneralFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.TaskInputFrame = TaskInputFrame()
        self.TaskOutputFrame = TaskOutputFrame()
        self.MapFrame = MapFrame()

        self.TaskInputFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.NW)
        self.TaskOutputFrame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.NW)
        self.MapFrame.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2)
    
    def place_widgets(self):
        self.TaskInputFrame.place_widgets()
        self.TaskOutputFrame.place_widgets()
        self.MapFrame.place_widgets()

    def forget_widgets(self):
        self.TaskInputFrame.forget_widgets()
        self.TaskOutputFrame.forget_widgets()
        self.MapFrame.forget_widgets()

class MainFrame(GeneralFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.switch_frames_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Switch Frame", command=self.change_screens)
        self.switch_frames_button.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.TaskFrame = TaskFrame()
        self.GliderFrame = GliderFrame()
        self.TaskFrame.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.TaskFrame.place_widgets()
        self.current_frame = 1

    def change_screens(self):
        if self.current_frame == 1:     
            self.TaskFrame.grid_forget()
            self.TaskFrame.forget_widgets()
            self.GliderFrame.grid(column=0, row=1)
            self.GliderFrame.place_widgets()
            self.current_frame = 2
        else:
            self.GliderFrame.grid_forget()
            self.GliderFrame.forget_widgets()
            self.TaskFrame.grid(column=0, row=1)
            self.TaskFrame.place_widgets()
            self.current_frame = 1

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1200x600")
        self.title("Gliding Task Analysis")
        self.main_frame = MainFrame()
        self.main_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W)

App().mainloop()
```

Comment: How can the issue be identified without a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot. Should be there now.

Comment: You need to specify the *parent/master* of the frames when creating them, otherwise they are all created as children of the root window.

Comment: I can only get button https://imgur.com/a/nivcfXc. The problem is map.

Comment: The best way recommended by acw1668

Comment: Might get a little bit like this.  https://ibb.co/dDztGMq

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).